# Как считать количество реакций в сообщении (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

### Как посчитать количество реакций раздельноm так, чтобы было не количество всех реакций, а одной нужной эмоции. Например:

---

В сообщении две реакции(возьмём крестик и галочку)
Как отдельно посчитать количество галочек и крестиков раздельно, так чтобы было:

```
Галочек - **x**
Крестиков - **y**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Решение вашей проблемы:**

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 1234567890:
        if payload.emoji.name == "Нужный вам эмодзи, например ":
            channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
            if reaction:
               reaction_counter = await reaction.count
```

В качестве `payload` отправляйте в функцию все необходимые ID, чтобы затем производить с ними необходимые манипуляции. `reaction_counter` присваивается количество упомянутых реакций `reaction` в сообщении с нужным ID на нужном канале. Для того, чтобы получить большее количество реакций, просто добавьте еще одну переменную по типу `reaction`, проверьте ее наличие и найдите количество упоминаний.